Passing Variables between Stages in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I am trying to pass a variable from one stage to another but somehow its is not working, I did check the other answers here on Stackoverflow but it didnt work (or maybe I am doing something wrong)
I am trying to pass the Variable $NEW_VERSION to the Cleanup Stage but in the output is empty:

This is my .yaml pipeline:
stages:
  - stage: ImageDeployment
    jobs:
      - job: NewImageDeployment
        timeoutInMinutes: 180
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - task: AzureKeyVault@2
            displayName: 'Fetch Secrets'
            inputs:
              connectedServiceName: '$(GLOBAL_SERVICE_CONNECTION)'
              keyVaultName: $(GLOBAL_KV_NAME)
              secretsFilter: "Packer-Secret"
              runAsPreJob: false

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Check image version'
            retryCountOnTaskFailure: 0
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(GLOBAL_SERVICE_CONNECTION)'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                while IFS=$'\t' read -a arr_image_versions; do
                  version=${arr_image_versions[0]}
                  date=${arr_image_versions[1]}
                  if [[ $date > $old_date ]]; then
                    last_version=$version
                  fi
                  old_date=$date
                done <<< "$(az sig image-version list --gallery-image-definition xxxxxxx --gallery-name xxxxxxxx --resource-group xxxxxxxxx --query "[].[name, publishingProfile.publishedDate]" -o tsv)"
                echo "Last image version: $last_version"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=last_version]$last_version"
            
          - task: Bash@3
            name: CheckImageVersion
            displayName: 'Increment image version'
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                IFS='.' read -ra VERSION_PARTS <<< "$(last_version)"
                PATCH_VERSION=${VERSION_PARTS[2]}
                PATCH_VERSION=$((PATCH_VERSION + 1))
                NEW_VERSION="${VERSION_PARTS[0]}.${VERSION_PARTS[1]}.$PATCH_VERSION"
                echo "New image version: $NEW_VERSION"
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION;isOutput=true]$NEW_VERSION"


  - template: tests/build_functionapp_testcase2.yaml@self

  - template: tests/datafactory_testcase3.yaml@self

  - stage: Cleanup
    condition: failed()
    jobs:
      - job: DeleteImage
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        variables:
          NEW_VERSION: $[ stageDependencies.ImageDeployment.NewImageDeployment.outputs['CheckImageVersion.NEW_VERSION'] ]
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "NEW_VERSION in Cleanup stage: $(NEW_VERSION)"
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Delete Packer Image'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(GLOBAL_SERVICE_CONNECTION)'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                echo "Deleting image version: $(NEW_VERSION)"
                az sig image-version delete --gallery-image-definition xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


On stage "Cleanup", you missed the option "dependsOn" to let stage "Cleanup" to depend on stage "ImageDeployment".
The "dependsOn" relationship also will ensure the stage "Cleanup" runs after the stage "ImageDeployment".
stages:
- stage: ImageDeployment

. . .

- stage: Cleanup
  dependsOn: ImageDeployment

If not set the "dependsOn" relationship, stage "Cleanup" cannot fetch the output from stage "ImageDeployment" when there are some other stages also are consuming the output from stage "ImageDeployment".
Related documentations:

Use outputs in a different stage


EDIT:
From the YAML you provided, I noticed you are using two fixed templates. If the names of stages defined in the templates also are fixed, on the stage "Cleanup", you can directly provide a list of stage names to the "dependsOn" option.
stages:
- stage: ImageDeployment

. . .
# Some stages from templates.
. . .

- stage: Cleanup
  dependsOn:
    - ImageDeployment
    - <name of stage_1 defined in templates>
    - <name of stage_2 defined in templates>
    . . .
    - <name of stage_N defined in templates>
  condition: failed()



Oh yes, thanks. I had overlooked the dependOn part. I want it to depend on all the stages and execute if any of the stages fail. However, I am using template stages. Could you please tell me how to achieve that?

@SumitBhardwaj consider adding a dependsOn parameter to the stages templates - you can find an example for job templates in DO: Create Configurable and Extensible Jobs, but you can do the same for stages as well. BTW that page is part of a repository I created some months ago, that contains coding guidelines for Azure YAML pipelines.

can it be done without a parameter?

@SumitBhardwaj, On the stage "Cleanup", you can directly provide a list of stage names to the "dependsOn" option. See EDIT.
